# debugging in eclipse source not found warning

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

When I am debugging in eclipse I want to step into the code lstEmployees method of personBUS but I get warning **Source not found**.

```
Map<String,Object> m =new HashMap<String,Object>();
    List l =  personBUS.lstEmployees();
    m.put("data", l);
    m.put("totalCount",l.size());
    m.put("success", true);
    return m;
```

Comment: add the code of this methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the Eclipse `project` where `personBUS` exists is different from the `project`, this code is.

You have to add the project of `personBUS` to the build path of the current project. This can be done as follows :

Right Click on project --> Configure Build Path --> Go to `Projects` tab --> Select the project where `personBUS` object's `class` exists.

Answer (score 0):

It means you are trying to `debug` a class which is inside a `jar` file, in your case the class represented by `personBUS` is in a jar file.
SOLUTION: Attach the source of the jar file to eclipse.

Comment: personBUS class is not in a .jar file. it is inside ...bus package.